# Передача параметров в конструктор

Tags: c#, .net

Пытаюсь передать параметры в конструктор другого класса, но параметры не передаются. Пробовал ставить `public`. Идентфикатор доступа не ставится. Подскажите, в чем дело?

```
public static void CallBook()
{
    string nameBook, authorBook, yearBook, madeBook;
    string[] booksName = Spisok.GetBookName();
    BooksAuthor newBook = new BooksAuthor();
    Console.WriteLine("\nЕсли хотите добавить новую книгу, введите Да."
        + " \nЕсли хотите удалить книгу, нажмите 'q'."
        + "\nЕсли хотите вывести информацию о книге введите R. \nЕсли хотите идити далее нажмите любую клавишу.");
    string otvet;
    otvet = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (otvet.ToString())
    {
        case "да":
        case "ДА":
        case "Да":
        case "дА":
            {
                Console.Write("\nВведите название книги: ");
                nameBook = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите автора книги: ");
                authorBook = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите год издания книги: ");
                yearBook = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите издательство книги: ");
                madeBook = Console.ReadLine();

                BooksAuthor book = new BooksAuthor(nameBook, authorBook, yearBook, madeBook);

                string message = null;
                Books.AddBook(newBook, ref message);
                Console.WriteLine(message);

            }; break;



        case "q":
        case "Q":
        case "Й":
        case "й":
            {
                Console.Write("\nВведите название книги: ");
                nameBook = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Write("Введите автора книги: ");
                authorBook = Console.ReadLine();
                if (Books.DeleteBook(newBook))
                    Console.WriteLine("Книга удалена из xml документа");
            }; break;

        case "R":
        case "r":
        case "К":
        case "к":
            Console.Write("Введите название книги: ");
            nameBook = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Введите автора книги: ");
            authorBook = Console.ReadLine();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> info in Spisok.GetBookDetails(nameBook, authorBook).BookInfo)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}\n", info.Value);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Передается в файл BooksAuthor в конструктор. Заносятся пустые значения:

```
public BooksAuthor(string nameBook, string authorBook, string yearBook, string madeBook)
{
    this.NameBook = nameBook;
    this.AuthorBook = authorBook;
    this.YearBook = yearBook;
    this.MadeBook = madeBook;
}
```

Comment: Что значит, не передаются? Ошибка компиляции? Или простопустые значения?

Кода слишком мало, не понятно, что за объекты newBook, Books.

Comment: Просто пустые значения.

Comment: Советую научиться пользоваться отладчиком, поставьте брейкпоинты и посмотрите что куда передается. В конструктор все нормально приходит. Ошибка в другом месте.

Comment: А где Вы проверяете, что не передается?

Comment: Я расставил breakpoint в конструктор попадают пустые значения.

Comment: я думаю может из-за того что конструктор не public, но идентификатор доступа не ставиться

Answer (score 2):

Пример инициализации полей через конструктор:

```
using System;

namespace Sample
{
    class Book
    {
        private string title;

        public Book(string title)
        {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public void OutputTitle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(title);
        }

    }

    class MyProcess
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Book book = new Book(Console.ReadLine());

            book.OutputTitle();
        }
    }
}
```

В том вашем коде, который приведен ошибки не видно, поэтому она может быть в том, что

1. устанавливаются и проверяются разные поля,
2. вообще проверяются не те данные, что надо.

Answer (score 0):

Если актуально еще, конечно.
Скорее всего проблема кроется вот в этом блоке:

```
case "дА":
            {
                /* удален блок кода */   
                // !!! Вот тут Вы создали переменную book с передачей параметров 
                BooksAuthor book = new BooksAuthor(nameBook, authorBook, yearBook, madeBook);

                string message = null;
                // !!! Вот тут вы добавили newBook, хотя выше создали book. Зачем?
                Books.AddBook(newBook, ref message); 
                Console.WriteLine(message);

            }; break;
```

Обратите внимание, что происходит:

1. В самом начале метода происходит инициализация `newBook`, вызывается конструктор без параметров.
2. Если было введено `да`, Вы собираете параметры и, вместо того, чтобы переписать переменную `newBook`, создаете новую переменную `book` и... все, **более ее не используете**.

Что можно сделать. Не создавайте `newBook` в самом начале, а создавайте по мере необходимости, к примеру. А так же, уберите конструктор без параметров у `BooksAuthor`, если это возможно, конечно.

Так же, я бы порекомендовал бы выделить из данного метода часть кода в виде отдельных методов, чтобы не было такого нагромождения.